# iOS - On ipad standby my application gets stuck

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I am using the following code to disable and enable View.

TO DISABLE VIEW.

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    _loadingSpinner.hidden = FALSE;
```

TO ENABLE VIEW.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
_loadingSpinner.hidden = true;
```

but when device goes into standby mode. application freezes. Users have close the application in the task pane in order to run it again.

Please HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint and check weather the code to end the interaction is hit at any time.
Why dont you use a overlay view with the spinner or `userInteractionEnabled` Property of UIView for the purpose?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I did that.. But I want to disable all the items in the screen. by using userInteractionEnable I need to do all the components disable/enable.. Also I did not find this function in UIBarButtonItem....

Answer (score 1):

Why are you disabling the view?  If you are wanting to prevent interaction while a process completes, why not use something like [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) or make your own Modal view and use that?